# Weird Qt SSL issue -- error "No Error" shows up, nothing else, and if I ignore it, everything works

Tags: windows, qt, ssl, error-handling

The issue is as follows : in my Qt app, I have a QWebView, which I use to load a HTTPS page.

Everything worked fine on my development machine, so I'm now trying to get it to run on a test machine. I ran the app, but the page didn't load (the QWebView was blank). After much debugging, I found the problem is that an SSL error shows up, and the sslErrors() signal is fired.

Here is my sslErrors() handling code:

```
void blah::sslErrors(QNetworkReply *reply, const QList<QSslError> &errors) {
  foreach(QSslError error, errors) {
    qDebug() << error.errorString() << endl;
  }
  reply->ignoreSslErrors();
}
```

The only thing the above code prints is:

```
"No error"
```

So there's no error, but unless I call `reply->ignoreSslErrors()`, the page doesn't load (on the test machine, on my developer computer no error is reported). Huh? Is this a bug?

Is it safe to ignore the error, if I make sure it's of the type "No error"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QSslSocket builds a NoError SslError [only when translating an OpenSSL `X509_V_OK` error](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/HEAD/src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_openssl.cpp#line1196).

The [OpenSSL documentation reports](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_get_verify_result.html#BUGS):

> If no peer certificate was presented, the returned result code is
>   X509_V_OK. This is because no verification error occurred, it does
>   however not indicate success.

You should use tcpdump or a similar tool to check that certificates are correctly exchanged between peers.

Answer (score 1):

You may be hitting QTBUG-28343 which is due to a binary incompatibility in openssl between the version your Qt was compiled against and the one you are running. This will be fixed in Qt 4.8.5.

http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/announce/2013-January/000020.html
https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28343