# Qt ignore SSL error

Tags: qt, ssl, signals-slots

I have had a look at several different attempts of ignoring SSL handshake errors in Qt but I have gotten none to work. I am using a self signed certificate and during development I would just like to ignore any error in case I have to change certs or something else happens.

I've looked at:

[Suppressing SSL errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277694/suppressing-ssl-errors)

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#sslErrors

https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17456

[Weird Qt SSL issue -- error "No Error" shows up, nothing else, and if I ignore it, everything works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166821/weird-qt-ssl-issue-error-no-error-shows-up-nothing-else-and-if-i-ignore-i)

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/48736-Ignore-SSL-Errors

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_ignore_ssl_errors_to_get_https_website_work_on_QML_Webview

http://xizhizhu.blogspot.se/2010/08/basic-samples-for-ssl-communication.html

**Here is my request code**

```
mManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
... // adding onRequestComplete slot and creation of postdata and request
QObject::connect(mManager, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)), this, SLOT(onSslError(QNetworkReply*, QList<QSslError>)));

QNetworkReply *reply = mManager->post(request, postData);
//QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)), this, SLOT(onSslError(QList<QSslError>)));
```

As you can see I have tried both to connect to the networkmanager signal and to the reply signal. Here are my slots:

```
void onSslError(QList<QSslError> errors) {
    QNetworkReply *reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
    reply->ignoreSslErrors();
}

void onSslError(QNetworkReply* r, QList<QSslError> l) {
    r->ignoreSslErrors();
}
```

When I make a regular HTTP request that works fine. Changing the QUrl in the request to https causes my issue. The error I get in my onRequestComplete slot is *"Could not initiate SSL context".*

I've tried setting breakpoints in both the slots and **they never trigger** and it seems to me that then the ignoreSslErrors call is never executed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It better to use it this way:

```
QList<QSslError> errorsThatCanBeIgnored;

errorsThatCanBeIgnored << QSslError(QSslError::HostNameMismatch, cert);
errorsThatCanBeIgnored << QSslError(QSslError::SelfSignedCertificate, cert);
    
ignoreSslErrors(errorsThatCanBeIgnored);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems I had to instal openssl.

Now working fine: http://codeblog.vurdalakov.net/2009/11/solution-qsslsocket-cannot-call.html